# SSO Options for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, single-sign-on

I'm looking for SSO options for .NET/C# and so far came across OpenID and DotNetOpenAuth. Have yet to look into them in detail but just wanted to ask for some suggestions of what else I should consider.

I'm looking to implement SSO for Google & Facebook, and ideally it would be a single 3rd party library that supports both, trying to avoid manually implemented each one.

If you've dealt with this previously, please share the approach/tools used.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID and DotNetOpenAuth are by far your best options.

Helpful Link for DotNetOpenAuth

http://www.tkglaser.net/2012/03/single-sign-on-using-facebook-in-asp.html

EDIT: DotNetOpenAuth home:

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Helpful Link for OpenID

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode25OpenIDEdition.aspx

Comment: Thanks I will be looking into these in more detail. I also came across this: http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/

Answer (score 1):

One other thing you might want to look into is the use of Azure ACS.
Here's an example [enabling Windows Live and Facebook](http://community.composite.net/Blog/2011/07/06/Facebook-and-Windows-Live-validation-using-Windows-Azure).

I've also used it against google credentials.

In this approach, you actually configure your application to interact only with Azure ACS, and configure which identity providers you want to enable through Azure's UI. So your application doesn't need to worry about each provider separately, and you could indeed add more providers without changing a single line of code in your application.